# What is Querydsl PathBuilder String parameter 'variable' used for

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

I'm working with Querydsl in my Spring Boot API for making some complex data filtering and when i declare the `PathBuilder` variable i've seen that first you have to pass statically your class  like `YourClass.class` and then a string `variable` for the constructor as shown below:

```
    PathBuilder<Plan> entityPath = new PathBuilder<>(Plan.class, "plan");
```

So i was wondering why is necessary this string parameter and also why its name has to be the same as my class name, because when i delete it or modified it, the `entityPath` doesn't work.

Comment: if you not set name of Component then spring will use the defaultl name is your class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PathExpression` (which `PathBuilder`) is by definition represents a path variable. In your case, the path ending up in your query would be `plan`. Consecutively, you can build on to this path and create various path types. For example property retrieval: `entityPath.get("someProperty")` will return a path expression that represents `plan.somePropety`. So you can't create `PathExpressions` without an alias, because it would be essentially meaningless.

Then why this alias is not always inferred from the Path types, well simply put: because it is not related. The underlying entities used may have different naming strategies, you may want to mix up different path variables of the same type, you might reference a node that has a particular alias by itself.

The alias doesn't have to be equivalent to the simple classname, it has to be equivalent to the alias it references from any of the from/join clauses in the query.

Comment: `The alias doesn't have to be equivalent to the simple classname, it has to be equivalent to the alias it references from any of the from/join clauses in the query.` well said !